# Website behavior data on a individual level

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, website-integration

I wanted to see what the best practise approach is on capturing website behavior data on a individual level using the tools within SFMC.

Objective: Capture individual level website behavioral data from campaigns deployed from SFMC.

Note: Part of the requirement would be once this data is in SFMC it would need to loop back to a central data lake. The idea being you don't need to use a tool like Google Analytics.

My thoughts on approaching this would be to setup "Collect Tracking Code" and then use a combination of queries/extracts to loop this out of SFMC.

Sources:

[Collect Tracking Code](http://help.marketingcloud.com/documentation/collect_code/)

[Web & Mobile Analytics](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/analytics_builder/web__mobile_analytics/)

My question in summary is:

A) Is this the recommended approach

B) Are there any issues with extracting this data

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really comment 100% on point A) as the recommended approach would really depend on what you need, but seems reasonable as far as collecting the data is concerned.
Regarding point B) you should know that the data is not by default available in SFMC. You will require a service engagement with Salesforce (contact your account exec for more details on this) to get the web tracking data pulled into the SFMC instance (as of July 2017). Once this data is there, you can use the SOAP API or Data Extract Activity to extract the required data from the Data Extensions.